# Calling all attributes of an object just by writting the object name once in python

Tags: python

So recently I was working with matplotlib here is my code

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    plt.plot([1,2,3] ,[2,4,6], label="line")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.title("Interesting graph")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Now as I have to write this **plt.** every single time which I feel is redundant

So my question is there any way that only once I have to write plt and I can call all the methods on it by just writing the method name

Here is an example of what I wanted which I am writing using with in python

```
with plt :
    plot([1,2,3] ,[2,4,6], label="line")
    xlabel("x")
    ylabel("y")
    title("Interesting graph")
    legend()

plt.show()
```

## ***If something like this is not present in python can I suggest this in python idea mailing list***

Comment: Not really, although you could import every attribute from `matplotlib.pyplot` into the current namespace with `from matplotlib.pyplot *`.

Comment: No i don't want that i have also used kotlin language they provide this feature using lambda run function so i thought if there is something similar here

Comment: Can i suggest this as an idea in python idea mailing list

Comment: ok give me the reason for downvote

Comment: @PPkpython. It's been suggested several times before, and is very unlikely to get any traction. Of course, if you had spent some time doing proper research you would have known that already. Maybe that explains why you've got those downvotes (not from me, btw).

Comment: Javascript has this feature, and confirmed through experience that it's a terrible idea. It's highly discouraged, and banned in strict mode.

Comment: @ekhumoro I googled it in the first place but i didn't got any proper link as something

Comment: @user2357112 can you explain why this can be a bad idea in python

Comment: downvoters please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, but if for some reason you really need/want a way to do what you're describing you could use an `OrderedDict` to retain the order that you want to call each function in and use the values as the arguments then use the `getattr` to dynamically make the function call.

It gets a little messy when you have keyword arguments but here's a hacky answer if you really need it. Hopefully it helps!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from collections import OrderedDict


def call_these_funcs_with_args(mod,ordered_funcs_and_args):
    """
    calls the functions provided as keys with the values provided as arguments
    for the module provided
    """

    for attr,args in attrs_and_args.iteritems():
        if attr in dir(mod):
            args = attrs_and_args[attr]
            if isinstance(args,list):
                getattr(mod,attr)(*args)
            elif args:
                getattr(mod,attr)(args)
            else:
                getattr(mod,attr)()
            if "{}_kwargs".format(attr) in attrs_and_args.keys() and isinstance(args,list):
                kwargs = attrs_and_args["{}_kwargs".format(attr)]
                getattr(mod,attr)(*args,**kwargs)


attrs_and_args = OrderedDict(
                 {'plot':[[1,2,3],[2,4,6]],
                  'plot_kwargs': {'label':'line'},
                  'xlabel':"x",
                  'ylabel':"y",
                  'title':"Interesting Graph",
                  'legend':None}
                  )


call_these_funcs_with_args(plt,attrs_and_args)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. this would decrease readability - so to understand one particular line of code you would need to scroll up ever time
2. name collisions would occur more often
3. code would become harder to reactor

alternative way is using method chaining (or "return-self") that does not have such disadvantages. but this approach works with methods calls only.